# Error with the urlDecodeAndEscape and to delete an item from the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, delete

When I delete an item from my cart (I clicked on X) I have this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Helper_Data::urlDecodeAndEscape() in /var/www/vhosts/mywebiste/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 787

The page is: http://mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/6990/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5hcnRpc3NpbWFsdWNlLml0L2NoZWNrb3V0L2NhcnQv/

I have Magento 1.9.1.0.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `urlDecodeAndEscape()` method was added in version 1.9.1.0

Did you make a clean install with version 1.9.1.0 or did you an upgrade from an older Magento version.

In case you made an upgrade check in `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php` on line `381` if the method `urlDecodeAndEscape` is available. Else I would suggest you make a fresh install with the latest version from Magento.

Comment: My files in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/ were edited (maybe an hacker?). I replaced them with a backup file and it works now! Thanks

Comment: I had similar situation; in my case the Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract was monkey patched in /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php and this caused the issue; maybe can help someone else